# Reverse array - out without first number

Tags: c++, arrays, reverse

I have a problem with exercise. I must give a few numbers and the program is to show them in reverse order but it doesn't show the last entered number.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

list <int> lista;

int main() {
    int liczba;
    while ((cin >> liczba) &&(getchar()!='\n')) {
        lista.push_front(liczba);
    }
    for(list<int>::iterator i=lista.begin();i != lista.end(); ++i)
        cout<<*i<<" ";

    return 0;
}
```

The same is with `std::vector`

Comment: When you input the last number and press *Enter*, `\n` will be added to the stream and `getchar()` will pick it up; but then your condition there fails, so the loop will not be entered.

Comment: *The same is with std::vector* -- In addition, since `vector` has no `push_front` function, you could have simply called `push_back` for both list and vector, and then loop using reverse iterators (`rbegin(), rend()`).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie or use `std::deque`

Comment: About vector changes i know but I didn't know about @getchar()  :)

Comment: @W.F. Even with `std::deque`, `push_back` and using reverse iterators works.  So that is the technique that will work with all 3 container classes, without changing any code (except for the container type).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'm not questioning the validity of your comment just suggesting that `std::deque` has `push_front` implemented and acts somewhat as `std::vector` (at least from the complexity perspective) :)

Comment: @Emilio [Usage of reverse iterators](http://ideone.com/Lvdid7)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie So rbegin () and rend () works correctly in these 3 complex types?

Comment: @Emilo -Yes, Using the `rbegin()` and `rend()` iterators are the standard ways to iterate backwards through a sequence container.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie  thanks for a useful way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you input the last number and press Enter, `\n` will be added to the stream and `getchar()` will pick it up; but then your condition there fails, so the loop will not be entered when the last value is read. You may want to additionally test `std::cin` then append the number.

```
while ((cin >> liczba) &&(getchar()!='\n')) {
    lista.push_front(liczba);
}
if(cin) 
    lista.push_front(liczba); //for the last item.
```